# How to determine that a given set of arcs form a cycle?

Tags: algorithm, search, graph, cycle

Please help me to solve this problem.
Let a complete oriented graph be given. We start randomly selecting arcs from it. How do we determine that choosing the next arc forms a cycle?

[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F7bv1.png)

For example, let us have a complete oriented graph with 6 vertices. We randomly choose the following arcs: 1-2, 4-5, 5-3, 5-6, 1-5, 3-4. How can we determine that after choosing the arc 3-4 a cycle 3-4-5-3 is formed?

Can you please tell me which algorithm and which data structure is better to use for this problem?

Perhaps some special tree would work for me, since I need an insert operation and a search operation, but I can't figure out which one.

Comment: A breadth-first-search (BFS) to encounter the cycle again.

Comment: This problem is often called "incremental cycle detection", but the algorithms for it aren't as good as one would hope, though they are faster than traversing after each insertion. Perhaps you could give us more context.

Answer (score 0):

A simple, but non-optimal way to detect that an arc forms a loop is to keep an adjacency-list representation of the (so-far cycle-free) network in memory, say for example as a

```
 map<node, list<node>> arcs;
```

Whenever you add a new arc from a to b, you would:

```
 arcs[a].push_back(b); // add edge a-b to the network
 test(b, a);           // call a DFS or BFS on 'b'; if 'a' found, a-b closes a loop
```

And the definition of test (in pseudo-C++, and using DFS, which is easier to implement than BFS, but which also may require expanding more nodes than BFS) could be:

```
bool test(node current, node goal) {
  if (goal == current) return true; // loop found!
  for (node next in arcs[current]) if (test(next, goal)) return true;
  return false;
}
```

Since we know that the network was cycle-free before adding the edge `a-b`, after adding this edge any cycle must include `a`. Note that this only *detects* the existence of the cycle. To get the actual cycle, you would need to, for example, keep and update a `map<node, node> parents` where following an edge from `current` to `next` would result in `parents.set(next, current)`. When you encounter your goal node again, you can simply backtrack through its parents to reconstruct the cycle.